# UIImage not loading URL

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsdata

My UIImage is not loading the URL I specified with [NSData datawithContentsOfURL:], even though the URL is (seemingly) correct.

Here's my configureCell: method:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  NSString *url = [photoUrls objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]; 

  cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imagewithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];  
}
```

Here's what is inside of the "photoUrls" array (excluding bullet points):

(

- http://fbcdn.net/fakeurl1/839.jpg
- http://fbcdn.net/fakeurl2/840.jpg
- http://fbcdn.net/fakeurl3/841.jpg

)

Comment: Can you add the output logs of the urls (make sure they are not nil) of the nsdata. Also make sure that when ever using urls from strings to use stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding

Comment: When I do NSLog(url) it gives me one url per line. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yea that was what I was after did using stringByReplacing... make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use [nsdata dataWithContentsOfURL:] in configure cell as it will block the UI. And also the way you have it, it will redownload all the images over and over again.

The following links will help you download the data asynchronously with out blocking the UI.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

With This SDWebImage all you have to do is: 
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                   placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
it will take care of downloading the image.

Comment: Thanks.. While I haven't tried it yet to see if it worked, I went ahead and marked it as the answer as it looks like what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your URLs don't point to valid images. All I see is `"Not found. Back to facebook"`. Your call to `[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]` will get the data, but `[UIImage imageWithData:]` will fail to generate a `UIImage` because the data doesn't represent a valid image.

Comment: Those weren't actual urls, they were only tests. I didn't want to put links to pictures I had up on FB.